# How to receive multiple checkboxes values and store properly in the database?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a form that has some fields/questions (Whats your email?, whats your phone number?) and then the user can select if that field should be included for the registration types that exist for a conference and also if that field should be mandatory or not for each registration type, through checkboxes. Example of the form layout:

[image]

For example, for the conference "test conference" there are two registration types (RT01 and RT02) and two questions "Whats your email?" and "whats your phone?".

In the form the user can select for each registration type if he wants to include both questions, just one, none, and for each included question the user can select if that question is mandatory or not for each registration type.

So, for example, if for the question "whats your email?" all checkboxes  ("Include for the registration type RT01", "Include for the registration type RT02", "mandatory for registration type RT01", "mandatory for registration type RT02") are checked and also for the question "Whats your phone?" all checkboxes are checked, it should be inserted in the pivot table "registration_type_questions" like this:

```
registration_type_id question_id required
 1                       1        1      (Include the question with id 1 in the registrationtype with id 1 and the question is mandatory for the registrationtype with id 1)
 2                       1        1    
  1                       2        1       
  2                       2        1
```

But is being inserted like:

```
registration_type_id question_id required
  1                       2        0       
  2                       2        0
```

Do you know where can be the issue? The code I have for now is this:

**Form to edit the conference registration form:**

```
  <form method="post" class="clearfix" action="{{route('questions.update', ['conf_id' => $conf->id])}}">

      {{csrf_field()}}

      <table class="table table-striped table-responsive-sm">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">Info</th>
        <th scope="col">Include for registration type</th>
        <th scope="col">Mandatory field</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    @foreach($question as $q)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$q->question}}</td>
            <td>
                @foreach($registration_types as $rtype)
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input autocomplete="off" name="question[{{$q->id}}][rtypes][]" class="form-check-input {{$rtype->name}}" type="checkbox" value="{{ $rtype->id }}" id="{{$rtype->id}}">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
                            {{$rtype->name}}
                        </label>
                    </div>
                @endforeach
            </td>
            <td>
                @foreach($registration_types as $rtype)
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input autocomplete="off"  name="question[{{$q->id}}][mandatories][]"
                               class="form-check-input mandatorycheckbox" type="checkbox" value="{{ $rtype->id }}" id="{{$rtype->id}}">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
                            for the registration type "{{$rtype->name}}"
                        </label>
                    </div>
                @endforeach
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach

    </tbody>
</table>      

      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-right mt-3" value="Update"/>
    </form>
```

**Question Model**

```
class Question extends Model
{

    public function registration_type(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\RegistrationType', 'registration_type_questions');
    }
}
```

**Registration type model**

```
class RegistrationType extends Model
{
    public function conference(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Conference');
    }

    public function questions(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Question', 'registration_type_questions');
    }
}
```

**Conferece model**

```
class Conference extends Model
{
   // A conference has many registration types
    public function registrationTypes(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\RegistrationType', 'conference_id');
    }
}
```

**QuestionController update method:**

```
 public function update(Request $request, $question_id){
        $question = $request->get('question');

        foreach($question as $key => $q) {
                //with "$outputArray = array_fill_keys($q["rtypes"], $q["mandatories"]);" it appears Undefined index: mandatories
            $outputArray = array_fill_keys($q["rtypes"], ["required" => false]);
            foreach ($outputArray as $lineKey => $line) {
                $line[$lineKey]["required"] = in_array($lineKey, $q["mandatories"]);
            }
        }

        $getQuestion = Question::find($key);
        if($getQuestion);
        $getQuestion->registration_type()->sync($outputArray);

        $this->validate($request, [
            ]);
    }
```

The `$questions` in QuestionController "`foreach($question as $key => $q) {`" has this content:

```
array:2 [▼
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "rtypes" => array:2 [▼
      0 => "1"
      1 => "2"
    ]
    "mandatories" => array:2 [▼
      0 => "1"
      1 => "2"
    ]
  ]
  2 => array:2 [▼
    "rtypes" => array:2 [▼
      0 => "1"
      1 => "2"
    ]
    "mandatories" => array:2 [▼
      0 => "1"
      1 => "2"
    ]
  ]
]
```

Comment: You are always inserting required as false, that's why it is always 0

Comment: Thanks, I'm inserting required as false to test because I'm not having success in getting properly the value of mandatories checkboxes. If I use " $outputArray = array_fill_keys($q["rtypes"], $q["mandatories"]); " it appears an error "Undefined index: rtypes". But even with this static with "false", then in the pivot table is only stored info for the question with id "2".

Comment: your input name is also wrong name="rypes[]

Comment: Thanks. I will update the question with that correction. But in my example, I have rtypes[].

Comment: you can not use [] in an object name. php will not read it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...[Both form and controller updated]

**updated registration form**

```
@foreach($question as $q)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$q->question}}</td>
            <td>
                @foreach($registration_types as $rtype)
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input autocomplete="off" name="include[{{ $q->id }}][{{ $rtype->id }}]" class="form-check-input {{$rtype->name}}" type="checkbox" value="1" id="{{$rtype->id}}">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
                                {{$rtype->name}}
                            </label>
                    </div>
                @endforeach
            </td>
            <td>
                @foreach($registration_types as $rtype)
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input autocomplete="off"  name="mandatory[{{ $q->id }}][{{ $rtype->id }}]"
                                   class="form-check-input mandatorycheckbox" type="checkbox" value="1" id="{{$rtype->id}}">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
                                for the registration type "{{$rtype->name}}"
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    @endforeach
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
```

**updated controller**

```
public function update(Request $request, $question_id)
{
    $includeArray = [];
    $includes     = $request->get('include');
    $mandatory    = $request->get('mandatory');

    //fetch all questions using required where conditions
    $questions = Question::get();    

    foreach($questions as $key => $question) { 
        if(!empty($includes[$question->id])) { 
            foreach($includes[$question->id] as $include => $value) { 
                if (!empty($mandatory[$question->id][$include]) && $mandatory[$question->id][$include] == 1) { 
                    $includeArray[$include] = ['required' => 1]; 
                } else { 
                    $includeArray[$include] = ['required' => 0]; 
                } 
            } 
        } else if(!empty($mandatory[$question->id])) { 
            foreach($mandatory[$question->id] as $mandatoryKey => $value) { 
                if (!empty($mandatory[$question->id][$mandatoryKey]) && $mandatory[$question->id][$mandatoryKey] == 1) { 
                    $includeArray[$mandatoryKey] = ['required' => 1]; 
                } else { 
                    $includeArray[$mandatoryKey] = ['required' => 0]; 
                } 
            } 
        } 
        $question->registration_type()->sync($includeArray); 
        $includeArray = []; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but like that is not inserting anything in the db. It is doing a query with conf_id as null: ""select * from `questions` where `conf_id` is null"".

Comment: Remove `where('conf_id', $request->get('conf_id')` and Change the line to ` $questions = Question::get();`

Comment: Thanks, but its not working properly. The queries that are executed are: string(25) "select * from `questions`" string(88) "select `registration_type_id` from `registration_type_questions` where `question_id` = ?" string(110) "insert into `registration_type_questions` (`question_id`, `registration_type_id`, `required`) values (?, ?, ?)" string(88) "select `registration_type_id` from `registration_type_questions` where `question_id` = ?" string(110) "insert into `registration_type_questions` (`question_id`, `registration_type_id`, `required`) values (?, ?, ?)"

Comment: If all checkboxes are checked the result appears, first row: "registration type id(1)", "question_id(1)", "required(0)". The second row "registration type id(1)", "question_id(2)", "required(0)".

Comment: @JohnZ what does the `dd($request->get('include')` and `($request->get('mandatory')` return if all checkboxes are selected.

Comment: "dd($request->get('include')" returns "array:2 [▼
  1 => array:2 [▼
    1 => "1"
    2 => "1"
  ]
  2 => array:2 [▼
    1 => "1"
    2 => "1"
  ]
]"

Comment: @JohnZ you sure `checkbox` named `include` render correctly.?

Comment: array:2 [▼
  1 => array:2 [▼
    1 => "1"
    2 => "1"
  ]
  2 => array:2 [▼
    1 => "1"
    2 => "1"
  ]
]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167348/discussion-between-ab-in-and-johnz).

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your pivot in your model via `->withPivot`.

```
class Question extends Model
{

    public function registration_type(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\RegistrationType', 'registration_type_questions')->withPivot('required');
    }
}
```

Then you can update it like this:

```
$getQuestion->registration_type()->updateExistingPivot($id, ['required' => 1]);
```

Where `$id` variable should contains registration_type id.

Comment: Thanks, do you know how to get the registration_type ids? I'm not having success getting them properly and also how to store the mandatory checkboxes properly?